# Working with Forms in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, outlook-form

My boss asked me to make a custom form in Outlook to streamline the process of sending automated form letters. Essentially what I need to do is have a few text boxes for input where the unique information goes (name, address, policy number, etc.), put it in the proper places in an otherwise standardized letter, and have it e-mailed. Making the input boxes was straightforward enough, but I don't have the slightest idea as to how to merge them into a standardized e-mail body.

My boss doesn't want a VB app (I could probably kludge a VB app myself), he specifically requested an Outlook form. I've done some googling to little avail (already seen the MS links on the topic, but they are far too generic to make any sense to me.

Can you guys help at all?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this tutorial:

http://www.msexchange.org/articles/Designing-Outlook-Forms-Part1.html
http://www.msexchange.org/articles/Designing-Outlook-Forms-Part2.html